# How to achieve StatusBar effect like in Medium or Telegram X apps?

Tags: java, android

Medium: [before scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00nd0.jpg) and [after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKdAX.jpg)

Telegram X: [normal if you have internet connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1dk5.jpg) and [otherwise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B3dI.jpg)

As you can see icons like Wi-Fi and others disappear; only currenct time and battery icon remain, but with 50% opacity.

Also, this effect is applied using smooth fade in and fade out animation.

EDIT: For everyone who need some info about this issue check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49182417/9342948

Comment: Check https://github.com/BaselHorany/ProgressStatusBar

Answer (score 1):

After searching for a while I found this. It automatically applies fadein and fadeout animation.

```
View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```