# Hide notifications effect in status bar. Android Programming

Tags: java, android-studio

Refer to the following  Example [image]

How to make effect of hidding notification icons in Status Bar. (Programmatically please).
I want to add this to my app.

Comment: Watchout this :: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16999638/7812329

Comment: @ChintanJoshi, no. I want to hide all notifications icons in Status Bar, when app is runned :)

Comment: Okay for that try this :: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19268653/7812329

Comment: @ChintanJoshi I want to create hide effect of all notifications. Look first screenshot (telegram x)

Comment: You want to set "text" instead of icon in notification bar. Right?

Comment: @ChintanJoshi i want to hide notifications in statusbar. Only effect! On first screenshot you can see clear statusbar without WIFI, Mobile Network, Vibration and other icons. Understand me? I want to add this feature to my app (right screenshot) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added this code. My problem was solved.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```

[ScreenShot with result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZHZJ.jpg)